# RC snubber not working when R > 0

Tags: power, switches, snubber, arc

I am running a 40 Ohm heating element directly connected to a 180 Volt, 8 A (@ max power) PV array. I am trying to use an RC snubber to protect the switch. I calculated the R and C values using this [guide](https://www.cde.com/resources/technical-papers/igbtAPPguide.pdf) and got

- R < 200/8 = 25 Ohm
- C < 1/(200^2*10) = 2.5 uF

where I used Vo = 200 V (open circuit voltage of the supply) and a (pessimistic) switching frequency of 10 hz. I wired up the snubber across a switch where the contacts are visible. I tried the following components:

- R: carbon film resistors from 1 to 10 Ohm, as well as no resistor.
- C: 630 V metallized film capacitors from .1 to 1 uF.

I observed the following:

- Without a snubber there is a big arc when opening the switch.
- With the RC snubber, for any R > 0, the arc is still present.
- If I remove the resistor, the arc is completely suppressed.

Why is such an apparently low resistance (compared to the guidelines) interfering with arc suppression?

Comment: A schematic showing how and where you connect these components would be far more helpful. When someone said "I connected ..." it often means they didn't connect it where they think they did.

Comment: If you have an oscilloscope, [this](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/calculate-an-r-c-snubber-in-seven-steps?CommentId=a4077a5e-4066-4019-91d4-dce1b7990d58) is probably the most practical way to design a snubber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically there will always be an arc with a resistor present in a snubber.

The slightest hint of the contact opening can cause the minutest of arcs but, you will get total suppression with just the capacitor because, it will soak up all the spark-current due to \$i = C\frac{dv}{dt}\$.

So, the switch starts to open and dv/dt will be massive thus, the current through the capacitor will also be fairly large and, unlimited by the presence of the resistor.

Comment: My understanding is that the reason for R is to limit the current when closing the swtich. But I am not seeing any signs of damage from the inrush with R = 0, at least nothing like the damage from arcing when R > 0. So is it safe to leave R=0?

Comment: The reason for R in a snubber can be twofold. (1) to dissipate inductive kick-back energy (the usual reason) or (2), limit the peak current through the capacitor to prevent it exceeding its data sheet limits. So, if the energy quenched when the switch opens is from inductive kick-back (the most normal use of a snubber), the current will already be limited and you won't need a resistor. However, if you need a fast quenching of that energy (some applications do) then adding a resistor will help because it burns that energy into heat.

Comment: In my case (see post) its a resistive load. So I should be worried that without a resistor, when I close the switch, I short the capacitor and subject it to too high current? How much of a concern is this for a metallized film capacitor being shorted a few times a day? This is the cap series I am using: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2864761.pdf

Comment: Polyprop caps are usually fine but, the data sheet covers hundreds of values and working voltages so I can't confirm. However, with a purely resistive load with minimal wiring inductance, it won't be an issue @saucerful

Comment: Thanks @Andy for all of your comments. But I'm still lost as to why several sources recommend that R < Vo / I (= 25 Ohm) should work, whereas in my case any R > 0 seems to prevent the snubber from doing its job?

Comment: Please link me to one of those sources.

Comment: https://www.cde.com/resources/technical-papers/igbtAPPguide.pdf

Comment: That paper is all about suppressing arcs from inductive loads and, in most cases, a resistor isn't needed except for speeding up the extinguishing of the energy on time critical applications (as previously mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to include the resistor **and** suppress the arc, by adding a forward-biased diode in parallel with the resistor, as described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkTgZ__0MjQ). Here is a screenshot of the circuit diagram:

[image]

Comment: There is really not any difference between this and having just the cap across the contacts.

Comment: Are you sure? I think when the switch opens there is no difference (the diode is forward biased) but when the switch closes the diode is reverse biased (relative to the cap) so the cap current must flow through the resistor, which limits the current and dissipates the energy instead of that happening in the switch itself.